# Overloaded methods - (Error C2664: Cannot convert from vector<T> to T)

Tags: c++, header-files, overloading, forward-declaration

I'm trying to call an overloaded method from the other overloaded member. I am getting an error `C2664: Cannot convert argument 2 from std::vector<PK_BODY_T*, std::allocator<_Other>> to PK_BODY_T`

Code:

```
std::vector<PK_BODY_t*> FillHoles(std::vector<std::vector<PK_EDGE_t>> holes, PK_BODY_t inputBody)
{
    std::vector<PK_BODY_t*> vectorBodies;
    PK_BODY_t *pointerInputBody = new PK_BODY_t(inputBody);
    vectorBodies.push_back(pointerInputBody);

    std::vector<PK_BODY_t*> returnVector;
    returnVector = FillHoles(holes, vectorBodies);  //<-- ERROR HERE. Calling overloaded method.

    delete pointerInputBody;
    return returnVector;
}

/* overloaded version of FillHoles 
*/
std::vector<PK_BODY_t*> FillHoles(std::vector<std::vector<PK_EDGE_t>> holes,     std::vector<PK_BODY_t*> inputBody)
{
    //...

    std::vector<PK_BODY_t*> fillHoleOutput = FillOneHole(currentBody, currentHole);

    return fillHoleOutput;
}
```

It appears as if the first method is trying to call itself here, instead of the second overloaded method. How do I force it to use the second method?

Comment: Is something wrong with me or you indeed **do** pass vector of vectors *by value*...?

Comment: For code questions you should have an [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You did not show how the functions are declared and in what scopes whether one function hides other function.

But in any case just declare the second overloaded function inside the first overloaded function

```
std::vector<PK_BODY_t*> FillHoles(std::vector<std::vector<PK_EDGE_t>> holes, PK_BODY_t inputBody)
{
    std::vector<PK_BODY_t*>  FillHoles(std::vector<std::vector<PK_EDGE_t>> holes, std::vector<PK_BODY_t*> inputBody);
    //...
```

Answer (score -1):

C++ files are compiled from top to bottom. From the vantage point of the top method, it cannot 'see' the second method, because it has not been compiled yet (as the second method is after the first method).

You must either declare methods in a header .h file, or forward declare the methods at the top of the .cpp file.

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/19-header-files/

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/17-forward-declarations/

Comment: You have answered your own question after 3 minutes. Why did you even post it instead of searching the solution by yourself **first**?